# Connect to all QML objects created via single Qt.createComponent call

Tags: qt, qml, components, connect, createobject

**Question**

How to create QML component in such a way that all objects created by the component will be connected in same way?

E.g. I would like the `triggered` signal of all objects created by `thirdPartyAPI` to be connected to `onTriggered` slot:

```
function onTriggered() { }
thirdPartyAPI.factory = Qt.createComponent("Trigger.qml")
```

**Why?**

I know I can create component, then create objects by the component and then parametrize (connect and set properties) each of created objects.

I use a 3rd party API that takes a component and creates objects inside. I have control over creation of the component but have no access to `Component.createObject` calls (it's inside the API).

I would like to obtain an effect similar to this: (I know there's no `newObjectCreated` signal on component)

```
var factory = Qt.createComponent(...)
factory.onNewObjectCreated: {
  newInstance.triggered.connect(onTriggered)
}
```

Comment: I tried searching through manuals and SO and haven't yet found the answer. I tried finding a signal issued when a component instantiates an object and could not find it, as I wrote. The actual question is under "what I need".

Comment: what is this library btw?

Comment: an in-house development, considered frozen at the moment.

Comment: What does the library do to the created the objects? Does it parent them to an object you have access to?

Comment: No, the object is a UI list, and the API shows them on screen. I wanted to provide custom behavior for the list instances in a code that creates component. Finally I've bypassed the restriction by creating component for the list inline in code, not loading it from URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the object creation procedure into some common function, for example:

```
function createMyObject(component, parent, params)
{
    var compo = Qt.createComponent(component);
    var obj = compo.createObject(parent, params);
    obj.customSignal.connect(onInstanceTriggered);
}
```

Comment: Problem is I have no control on createObject calls inside some API which is out of my control. I load a component from qml file, provide it to the API and it creates objects inside.

Comment: You should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear now what do you want to archive.

Comment: Ok, but if you have no reference to a newly created object but only to component you have no way to connect to its signals.

Comment: Yes, and I hoped there's some way to provide parametrization for all objects not yet created, and which would be applied to an object after it is created.

Comment: Sure, if you have access to the created object, but it rather refers to API then 
 to QML.

Comment: I just start using QML and can easily miss a standard existing QML way to bypass this API restriction, that's why I asked.